# Magento Description/Attributes Replace?

Tags: php, xml, magento

**I'm having trouble swapping Short Description (Quick Overview) with Additional Information (Attributes)**

*Here's an image better explaining what I'm trying to accomplish:*

[image]

---

I posted links to CodePaste.net

[Here is my View.PHTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629130451/http://codepaste.net:80/aji7c1)

[Here is my Attributes.PHTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629125152/http://codepaste.net:80/kpv199)

[Here is my Tabs.PHTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629022211/http://codepaste.net:80/pfukb6)

[Here is my Catalog.XML](https://web.archive.org/web/20120629130255/http://codepaste.net:80/bzeafz)

> ***I know most files posted are not involved, but I figured it might help.
> Any help or questions are greatly
> appreciated. Thanks!***

Comment: external links are evil.

Comment: It's only CodePaste.net, lol. Any idea with a solution to my problem?

Comment: "I know most files posted are not involved, but I figured it might help. Any help or questions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!". No, it really doesn't. You know your code better than us. Whilst it might be easy for you to disregard irrelevant code, we have to read it all. And that's a lot of code to read. If you reduce the posted code to only relevant snippets, you stand a much increased chance of a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In catalog.xml you have

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>upsell_products</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
</block>
```

Remove the last "addTab" line to remove the "Additional information" tab.

Add

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.info.additional" as="additional_info" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml" />
```

just below

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.tierprices" as="tierprices" template="catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml"/>
```

(which is located a few lines up). Now, in View.phtml you insert

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional_info'); ?>
```

and you reverse the procedure to move Quick Overview.

NB. You might need to adjust the template files.

Answer (score 0):

Could you draw a picture that to swap attributes for the product's page how to rebuild?